# Can't remove space from top of the div

Tags: html, css

I have one `div` inside that i have one `label`. But I am getting some space above the `div`. I can't remove that space any how.

Don't know what happens there.

**Question:** Why I am getting that space above `div`?  How can I remove that space?

**My code:**

For display issue proper I had put `color` and `border`.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  background: green;
}

label {
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label>Some text</label>
</div>
```

I have tried many things but, didn't get any solution.

Comment: Try `vertical-align: top;` on the `label`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`label` is a inline element therefore add `display:inline-block/block` or `vertical-align:top`

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
div {
  font-size: 0;
  /* fix inline-block gap - not needed when using block only*/
  background: red
}
label {
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 10px;
}
.l1 {
  display: inline-block
}
.l2 {
  display: block;
  width: 9%
}
.l3 {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label class="l1">Some text</label>
</div>

<div>
  <label class="l2">Some text 2</label>
</div>

<div>
  <label class="l3">Some text 3</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to add `vertical-align: top;` for your label

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  background: green;
}

label {
  vertical-align: top;
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label>Some text</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour is caused because the `div` element has a browser-dependent default size applied to it. When it contains an element with a smaller font-size, the contained element will be placed on the baseline of the `div` which results in the space. To solve it, add a matching font size to the `div`:

```
div {
    font-size: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is coming because of the default `line-height` of the labels. You need to use `reset.css` or similar (like `normalize.css`) to clear the browsers default styling.

Here are some helpful reference, download and simply add them above your style sheet.

```
http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/reset.css
```

or

```
https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/3.0.3/normalize.css
```

Answer (score -1):

Inline element like `span` also behaves the same.

Add a float:left for the label

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  background: green;
}

label {
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 10px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label>Some text</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Looks like the `line-height` in the `div` is too high.

This does the trick:

```
div {
  line-height: 10px;
}
```

(Of course you should reference the div with a class or id).